# Using providers from shared module in testing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic project which I want to test. The `HomePage` looks like this.

```
export class HomePage{
  constructor(public alert: AlertController){}
}
```

This is how my test looks

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [IonicModule ],
      declarations: [ HomePage],
      providers: []
    });
    TestBed.compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomePage);
  })
```

From [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/7000b1b173a41eb121a0c51da41c9a00f4fc2f33/src/index.ts), `IonicModule` have added providers for `AlertController`. So the `imports: [IonicModule]` should take care of `AlertController` DI. But This throws an error `No provider for AlertController`. I know I can add it to `providers` and get it working, but isnt importing IonicModule enough?